# Can't loop through a column for QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I need some assistance, because this problem simply doesn't make sense... Indentation is looking a bit off sorry for that...

```
self.myData = [["facebook-icon", "Facebook", str(self.mykeys[0][1]), "*" *len(self.passes[0])], ......
```

Only the first item in the table is getting populated, even though the rowCount prints out the number 3.. thats what is puzzling me.. would love someone trying out this code, I am a Python newbie

```
    passAmount = len(self.myData)
    print("There are %x items in myData" % (passAmount))

    rowCount = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    print("There are %x items in the table" % (rowCount))

    for row in range(0, rowCount):
        cellText = self.tableWidget.itemAt(row,0).text()

        if(cellText == "facebook-icon"):
            self.tableWidget.itemAt(row, 0).setText("")
            print(imagePaths[0])
            fb = QPixmap(imagePaths[0]).scaledToWidth(20)
            label = QLabel()

            label.setPixmap(fb)

            # label.setScaledContents(True)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, label)


        elif(cellText == "blogger-icon"):
            ...


    self.tableWidget.setFont(self.font)
    self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_table_click)



    # Show widget
    self.show()
```

Am I doing somethin wrong??

[image: App example]

Comment: https://github.com/Josep-Jesus-Bigorra-Algaba/MyKeyLogger

Comment: I made a PR to your repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you want to get elements from the first column, but `itemAt()` does not return the item given a row and column but to a geometric position, instead you should use the `item()` method. In addition we can reduce code using a dictionary:

```
dict_icons = {
    "facebook-icon": imagePaths[0],
    "blogger-icon": imagePaths[1]
}

for row in range(0, 3):
    item = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0)
    image_path =  dict_icons.get(item.text())
    if image_path is not None:
        item.setText("")
        pixmap = QPixmap(image_path).scaledToWidth(20)
        label = QLabel(pixmap=pixmap)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, label)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I want to try and also take time to give back to the community in what I can.. going to approve the PR tomorrow  cheers